# Disabling 'allowfullscreen' from the youtube in the javascript

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, fullscreen, fullscreenchange

To prevent double click fullscreen from the iframe all you do is remove '**allowfullscreen**' from the iframe code.

```
<iframe width="606" height="344" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE" frameborder="0" /*allowfullscreen*/></iframe>
```

But how would it be done through the youtube javascript api if you’re not using the iframe?

I can’t seem to figure it out

This seems like it would be simple to do but I can't seem to figure it out.

**How would this be done?**

I've been looking all over and haven't found any code that does this.

Nothing I'm trying seems to be working at all.

If it's able to be done via the **iframe**, shouldn't it be able to be done through the **javascript** also?

**Also:** fs: 0; **Doesn't remove Double click fullscreen.**

https://jsfiddle.net/zb6mkug3/829/

```
<div class="player"></div>

    (function iife() {
    "use strict";
    const tag = document.createElement("script");
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
    const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        const youtubePlayer = event.target;
        youtubePlayer.setVolume(0); // percent
    }
    window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = function() {
        new YT.Player(document.querySelector(".player"), {
            height: '315',
            width: '560',
            host: 'https://www.youtube-nocookie.com',
            videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
            playerVars: {
                controls: 1,
                fs: 0,
            },
            events: {
                "onReady": onPlayerReady
            }
        });
    };
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

In `playerVars`, simply add `fs: 0`, that will disable the fullscreen choice:

```
playerVars: {
    controls: 1,
    fs: 0
},
```

[source](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?playerVersion=HTML5)

Comment: That doesn't work. Double click fullscreen is still enabled. It doesn't remove that. I want to remove the double click fullscreen.

Comment: If you want to disable the doubleclick-fullscreen you'll have to do so in the browser preferences. It's not a Youtube API option, rather than a browser-related thing.

Comment: How come it works by removing 'allowfullscreen' from the iframe? That disables it. Wouldn't there be something that works the same way with the javascript?

Comment: `allowfullscreen` is an attribute of iframe. I'm not too familiar with iframe so I had to look it up and found this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe. So apparently you'll have to look into `Element.requestFullScreen`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullScreen

Comment: This works in Firefox, but not Chrome.
https://jsfiddle.net/zb6mkug3/359/ videoPlayer.allowFullscreen = false; But I can't find something that will work with Chrome.

Comment: As a dirty hack, `videoPlayer.allow = none;` works in Chrome, but it might break other things since `allow` is not only about fullscreen of course...

Comment: I tried adding all of this stuff: fullscreenchange",webkitfullscreenchange"msfullscreenchange",  mozfullscreenchange", "false," But none of that worked either https://jsfiddle.net/zb6mkug3/835/